# How to use a different protocol with $AbsoluteLink in Silverstripe

Tags: php, silverstripe

In the **Silverstripe templating** syntax `$AbsoluteLink` returns the full URL of a page/object, including the protocol and host:

```
http://www.example.com/event/ics
```

I want to be able to call a full URL with a different protocol:

```
webcal://www.example.com/event/ics
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a custom link method that replaces the current website protocol with your desired one. ie.

```
public function WebCalLink()
{
    return str_replace(Director::protocol(), 'webcal://', Director::protocolAndHost()) . $this->Link();
}
```

Comment: Isn't $this->Link() is the relative link? so str_replace will not work in this case?

Comment: The str_replace is not operating on $this->Link(), it's operating on Director::protocolAndHost()

Answer (score 5):

Make a new getter function on your page:

```
public function WebcalLink() {
    $absolute = $this->AbsoluteLink();
    $webcal = str_replace(Director::protocol(), "webcal://", $absolute);
    return $webcal;
}
```

You can call it from your template using $WebcalLink